# how to filter openPanel to show only those files that WebView can open?

Tags: macos, webview, mime, uti, nsopenpanel

NSOpenPanel can filter files it displays dimming those files not included in: setAllowedFileTypes:.

How do I use this to dim those files that WebView (OS X) can not display?

Thanks